# jQuery Sticky Waypoints Direction option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I am using the combination of jQuery Waypoints and it's plugin "sticky elements". Based on the documentation (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) I am using the following code

```
$('#nav').waypoint('sticky', {
  direction: 'up',
  stuckClass: 'stuck'
});
```

The plugin functions and the element becomes sticky, the problem is it does not seem to take in to account the direction in which the user scrolls (up or down); and it becomes sticky regardless of the direction. According tot he documentation it should only be becoming sticky on upward scrolling.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.11.1 and waypoints 2.0.4

Comment: Can you include some sample markup and css for your stuck class? I'm just trying to picture the desired behaviour. So you want to be able to scroll down past the element, but then on the way back up, the element would stick to the bottom or top of the page?

Comment: Yes. The stuck class simply has the position: fixed, when scrolling up the header nav needs to stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in an issue on the repo, but I will mirror it here:

The `direction` option for the Sticky shortcut wasn't added until 2.0.5. Upgrading to 2.0.5 should solve this.